# linux blocking socket read returns 0 bytes but the connection is NOT disconnected

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I am testing the behavior of linux tcp socket with server socket never close and keep in loop sending string to the client, and the client read the string, however, I find it wired that the client read() returns 0 bytes will there is no data arrived. I have search stackoverflow for similar problems but all answers tells that "read returns 0 bytes for a blocked socket means the server has disconnected the connection", I am confused as in my test code, the server never close the socket, and netstat also shows the connect in in ESTABLISHED mode.
Here is some of my test code:

SERVER CODE:

```
if((new_fd=accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)(&client_addr),&sin_size))== int(-1))
{
    exit(1);
}

int i=0;
while(1)
{
    //never ending loop
    char buf[20] = {0};
    sprintf(buf,"packet %d\n",i++);
    if(write(new_fd,buf,strlen(buf))==-1)
    {
        cout<<"write error"<<strerror(errno)<<endl;
        break;
    }
    sleep(5);
}
close(new_fd);
close(listenfd);
```

CLIENT CODE:

```
while(1) {
    //never ending loop
    int  ret = read(sock_cli, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf));
    if(ret==-1)
    {   
        cout<<"recv failed. err="<<strerror(errno)<<endl;
        break;
    }   
    else if(ret==0) {
        cout<<"recv completed. err="<<strerror(errno)<<endl;
        sleep(1);
        continue;
    }   
    else
    {   
        recvbuf[ret] = 0;
        fputs(recvbuf, stdout);
        continue;
    }   
}
```

And the client keeps output like:

```
packet 55
recv completed. err=Success
recv completed. err=Success
recv completed. err=Success
recv completed. err=Success
recv completed. err=Success
packet 56
recv completed. err=Success
recv completed. err=Success
recv completed. err=Success
recv completed. err=Success
recv completed. err=Success
packet 57
recv completed. err=Success
recv completed. err=Success
recv completed. err=Success
recv completed. err=Success
recv completed. err=Success
packet 58
recv completed. err=Success
```

Any idea why the client is not blocking at read but returns 0?

Comment: A blocking socket will never return 0. It will block until it can return > 0 bytes, or return -1 if the connection is closed.

Comment: by default the socket is in blocking mode, so how to explain that the client keeps printing "recv completed. err=Success" between real packets arrival?

Comment: oh, wait, you are calling `read()`, not `recv()`. `read()` behaves differently. Try calling `recv()`.

Comment: Although the manpage of recv writes " If no messages are available at the socket, the receive calls wait for a message to arrive, unless the socket is nonblocking (see fcntl(2)) in which case the
       value -1 is returned and the external variable errno set to EAGAIN.".  Actually I've tested recv(), and either set the flags to 0 or MSG_WAITALL, both acts no different with the read().. I am in kernel 2.6.32.

Comment: You are sending zero length packets, so `read()` is returning zero. This is a bug in the kernel. Nothing should be sent and nothing should be received. NB There is no point in printing `errno` if `ret` isn't -1. Its value is undefined and of no interest.

Comment: @JamesPolk (1) A blocking read will return zero at end of stream. (2) `read()` behaves differently how? Please clarify and substantiate your assertion.

Comment: @EJP thanks for the explanation about sending of 0 byte, however, I could not see anywhere that 0 byte is sent, even though I remove the write() section from the server code, the client still receives 0 byte right after accept() returned at the server side..

Comment: @WenqingChen You are sending from a buffer containing `{0}`, i..e starting with a null, and determining the length to send via `strlen(buf)`, which will be zero, because the initial `null` terminates `strlen()` before it has counted anything. Try `sizeof buf` instead..

Comment: @EJP thanks for elaborating.. however, it seems not the problem, as the buffer is actually never empty, even if I remove the write() from the server side, leave only accept(), the client still receives 0 bytes. Seems the client receive 0 bytes immediately right after server call accept()..

Comment: The result of your `strlen()` call is zero, for the reason I gave, and that is the value of the 'length' parameter you are providing to `send()`. You don't appear to understand your own code. If you remove the `write()` from your `while (1)` loop it will just spin mindlessly forever without sending anything: if that is what it is really doing your client won't receive anything.

Comment: I am sorry I've just made a mistake that I called shutdown(sock_cli,SHUT_RD) of the client socket before calling read()... So  it is reasonable read() returns 0 bytes immediately.. However, it is wired when the server sends something to the client, read() and still work after SHUT_RD. This behavior has been explained in <<The Linux Programming Interface>> author Michael Kerrisk, section 61.2 describing that TCP sockets did not support SHUT_RD well.

Comment: `read()` should keep returning zero forever after `SHUT_RD`. Linux has several bugs in this area.